# How do I list all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a homework my prof assigned.

> List all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$

Since $X^3+X+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and its degree is 3, it is irreducible.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field, $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ is a PID.

Thus, $X^3 + X + 1$ is a prime element in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$, hence $<X^3+X+1>$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ is a PID, $\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal.

This concludes that $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$ is a field.

(I described this process since I want to show you that it's not the case I'm not doing anything and asking you to do my homework).

However, I have no idea how to list all those elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$.

I'm not sure that whether is is even finite or not.

Here is how I tried:

> Well, $\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$ is definitely an element and all elements are of the form $f+\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$.
>
> Since my prof wants me to list all elements, there must be a pattern in listing or $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/\langle X^3+X+1\rangle$ must be finite.
>
> Then, what to do?

Would someone please give me some hints?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are declaring $X^3 = -X - 1$. How many polynomials can there be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** List all polynomials of degree $\le 2$. There are $8$ of them. The equivalence classes of these are the elements of our field.

The listing is easy. For full information one should then give the addition and multiplication tables. Doing the multiplication table is a little tedious, but luckily it is a small table. Roughly speaking we multiply in the natural way, and replace $X^3$ by $X+1$, and therefore $X^4$ by $X^2+X$.

Comment: You are welcome. At one level these fields are very concrete.